Encountered an issue deploying my website (Vite+React) to GitHub Pages
I'm using TanStack Router to create routes for my website, and everything works well when navigating through the application. However, I'm encountering a 404 error when I refresh a route page or access it directly on GitHub Pages. The error message indicates File not found.
Vite Configuration
//I have set the base URL in my vite.config.ts file to /portfolio:

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';
import { TanStackRouterVite } from '@tanstack/router-plugin/vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), TanStackRouterVite()],
  base: '/portfolio/',
});

File-Based Routes
My project structure for routes is as follows:
- portfolio
  - index.lazy.tsx
  - about
    - index.lazy.tsx
  - etc...

GitHub Actions Deployment
I deployed my app using the following deploy.yml configuration:
name: Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Setup Node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3

      - name: Install dependencies
        uses: bahmutov/npm-install@v1

      - name: Build project
        run: npm run build

      - name: Upload production-ready build files
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: production-files
          path: ./dist

  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: production-files
          path: ./dist

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: ./dist

[https://samir0ps.github.io/portfolio]
[https://github.com/samir0ps/portfolio]
You can view my website here and the total code.
I configured my Vite project to use TanStack Router for routing, set the base URL in vite.config.ts, and organized my routes using a file-based structure. Additionally, I created a GitHub Actions workflow (deploy.yml) to automate the build and deployment process to GitHub Pages.
I expected the website to function correctly, including seamless routing through TanStack Router, even when refreshing a route page or accessing it directly on GitHub Pages. Specifically, I anticipated that my configuration and deployment setup would prevent 404 errors on page refresh, ensuring that all routes are correctly handled.

I fixed this error by creating 404.html file in the public folder which containes :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>React Router</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Number of path segments to keep in the URL
      var pathSegmentsToKeep = 1;
      
      // Get the current location object
      var l = window.location;
      
      // Rebuild the URL
      var newUrl =
        l.protocol + "//" + l.hostname + (l.port ? ":" + l.port : "") + 
        l.pathname.split("/").slice(0, 1 + pathSegmentsToKeep).join("/") + 
        "/?/" + 
        l.pathname.slice(1).split("/").slice(pathSegmentsToKeep).join("/").replace(/&/g, "~and~") + 
        (l.search ? "&" + l.search.slice(1).replace(/&/g, "~and~") : "") + 
        l.hash;
      
      // Check if the current URL does not already match the new URL to avoid infinite redirect loop
      if (l.href !== newUrl) {
        l.replace(newUrl);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>

And I added a script to the index.html file of the application :
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="../portfolio/src/assets/logo.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function (l) {
        if (l.search[1] === "/") {
          var decoded = l.search
            .slice(1)
            .split("&")
            .map(function (s) {
              return s.replace(/~and~/g, "&");
            })
            .join("?");
          window.history.replaceState(null, null, l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash);
        }
      })(window.location);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class=" bg-darkmain text-light">
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I hope this is helpful.
